# OBJECT TAG and Event Listening for VIDEO and AUDIO

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am working in an environment of Windows 7, VDI and SharePoint. This combo has lag/delay problems with HTML5 VIDEO/AUDIO Player. We are thus required to revert back to OBJECT tag video playing.

We need to track user activity on videos being watched. In JavaScript, is there an option for OBJECT/PARAM tags similar to HTML5's video.currentTime and video.duration? If there is, how might that look like?